# Filter the JSON array of objects according to multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON array of object. I am creating a filter to filter this data.

```
var allData = {
  "items":[
     {
       "orderNumber": 1010,
       "area": "JAPAN",
       "category": "orange",
       "orderApprover": "John Smith"
     },
     {
       "orderNumber": 1020,
       "area": "EM-JAPAN",
       "category": "red",
       "orderApprover": "Paul Smith"
     },
     {
       "orderNumber": 1013,
       "area": "EMEA",
       "category": "orange",
       "orderApprover": "Mike Smith"
     },
     {
       "orderNumber": 1140,
       "area": "APAC",
       "category": "yellow",
       "orderApprover": "Jake Smith"
     }
]}
```

If Filter condition is: (Find items where orderNumbers contains 10)

Then Output:

```
{
  "items":[
     {
       "orderNumber": 1010,
       "area": "JAPAN",
       "category": "orange",
       "orderApprover": "John Smith"
     },
     {
       "orderNumber": 1020,
       "area": "EM-JAPAN",
       "category": "red",
       "orderApprover": "Paul Smith"
     },
     {
       "orderNumber": 1013,
       "area": "EMEA",
       "category": "orange",
       "orderApprover": "Mike Smith"
     }
]}
```

If Filter condition is: (Find items where orderNumbers contains 114)

Then Output:

```
{
  "items":[
    {
      "orderNumber": 1140,
      "area": "APAC",
      "category": "yellow",
      "orderApprover": "Jake Smith"
    }
]
}
```

If Filter condition is: (Find items where orderNumber contains 10 and area contains EM)

Then Output:

```
{
  "items":[
     {
       "orderNumber": 1020,
       "area": "EM-JAPAN",
       "category": "red",
       "orderApprover": "Paul Smith"
     },
     {
       "orderNumber": 1013,
       "area": "EMEA",
       "category": "orange",
       "orderApprover": "Mike Smith"
     }
]}
```

Is there a way to achieve concatenation of successive filters?

EDIT: I am trying to make it general.

I have stored the filter field values in state object.

```
this.state = {
  orderNumberData: '',
  areaData: '',
  .
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Array selectedFilters stores the filters.

Like this:

```
selectedFilters = [orderNumberData, areaData,........]
```

How can i iterate now and achieve desired filter. I am trying to loop through selectedFilters array and check for each item that includes desired string. I don't know how to fill the blank with JSON object field based on selectedFilters array. Some sort of mapping between both is required. Let's say if selectedFilters[1] = orderNumberData, then orderNumber should go in that blank.

```
for(var i=0; i<selectedFilters.length; i++) {
   allData.items.filter(item => item.________.toString().includes(this.state[this.state.selectedFilters[i]]))
}
```

This works if i have hard coded the JSON fields.

```
allData.items.filter(item => item.orderNumber.toString().includes(this.state[this.state.selectedFilters[i]]))
```

Comment: you should check out some documentation on the filter method https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could move the constraints info a filter array and filter by checking all (AND condition) constraints with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) or if you want only some (OR condition), take [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
var data = [{ orderNumber: 1010, area: "JAPAN", category: "orange", orderApprover: "John Smith" }, { orderNumber: 1020, area: "EM-JAPAN", category: "red", orderApprover: "Paul Smith" }, { orderNumber: 1013, area: "EMEA", category: "orange", orderApprover: "Mike Smith" }, { orderNumber: 1140, area: "APAC", category: "yellow", orderApprover: "Jake Smith" }],
    filters = [
        o => o.orderNumber.toString().includes('10'),
        o => o.area.includes('EM')
    ],
    result = data.filter(o => filters.every(fn => fn(o)));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks @Nina Scholz. Having multiple filters defined at one place is a good advice. Will try this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter,but since `orderNumber` is an integer use `toString` to convert it to string and then use `includes` to check if the values contains the desired number

```js
var allData = {
  "items": [{
      "orderNumber": 1010,
      "area": "JAPAN",
      "category": "orange",
      "orderApprover": "John Smith"
    },
    {
      "orderNumber": 1020,
      "area": "EM-JAPAN",
      "category": "red",
      "orderApprover": "Paul Smith"
    },
    {
      "orderNumber": 1013,
      "area": "EMEA",
      "category": "orange",
      "orderApprover": "Mike Smith"
    },
    {
      "orderNumber": 1140,
      "area": "APAC",
      "category": "yellow",
      "orderApprover": "Jake Smith"
    }
  ]
}



let data = allData.items.filter(item => item.orderNumber.toString().includes('10'));

console.log(data)
```

You can further fine tune the filter callback to integrate search for EM

Comment: Thanks @brk. Will be trying to add conditions on successive filter operations.

Answer (score 0):

We can get a dynamic filtering done by placing the filter criteria in an external array. In my example it is `filterCond` array.

Then iterate over the filter conditions array and check each value of the object property whether that is matching with the data in the `filterCond` array in the *same* index.

If the condition is false increment a counter, and return false if counter is greater than 0.

The criterias should be placed *as per the index of the keys* in the object.

```js
var allData = {"items":[{ orderNumber: 1010, area: "JAPAN", category: "orange", orderApprover: "John Smith" }, { orderNumber: 1020, area: "EM-JAPAN", category: "red", orderApprover: "Paul Smith" }, { orderNumber: 1013, area: "EMEA", category: "orange", orderApprover: "Mike Smith" }, { orderNumber: 1140, area: "APAC", category: "yellow", orderApprover: "Jake Smith" }]};

function getFilteredData(allData, filterCond){
 return allData.items.filter((itm) =>{
  count = 0;
  filterCond.forEach((cond, idx) => {
     count = Object.values(itm)[idx].toString().includes(cond) === false ? count + 1: count;
  })
  return count === 0;
});
}
console.log("Filtering by orderNumber 10 and area EM");
let filterCond = ["10", "EM"];
console.log(getFilteredData(allData, filterCond));

console.log("Filtering by orderNumber 114");
filterCond = [114];
console.log(getFilteredData(allData, filterCond));

console.log("Filtering by only orderNumber 10");
filterCond = [10];
console.log(getFilteredData(allData, filterCond));

console.log("Filtering by only area APAC");
filterCond = [, "APAC"]; //leaving first criteria blank
console.log(getFilteredData(allData, filterCond));
```

Comment: can you please elaborate the approach. What was the significance of count here??

Comment: @Deepak Laxkar count determines whether any of the filter conditions didn't match. if there is an mismatch the count will be non zero. With that I can get to know that some values were not present in object.